# Boundary conditions for Clevis fork (linear elasticity)

Tags: structural-analysis, finite-element-method, elasticity

consider the Clevis fork domain (see here for an image https://www.traceparts.com/it/product/camloc-motion-control-h1-stainless-steel-clevis?CatalogPath=TRACEPARTS%3ATP01001005&Product=10-12112014-075680&PartNumber=084337) and the linear elasticity equation on it. What are suitable boundary conditions that can be applied on such a domain? Even the simplest possible ones are fine, as long as they have physical meaning. I tried to search on the net but I didn't manage to find a clear setup!

***EDIT:***

Let's call $u_D$ the displacement field and $f$ the load (the rhs of the equation). Also, let $A,B$ be the surfaces of the two holes of the clevis (where the pin is passing through) and $C$ the annulus at the front of the clevis.

If I understood correctly:

- $u_D = 0$ on $A$ and $B$
- $\sigma \cdot n=(1e6,0,0)$ on $C$
- $f=0$

What I mean with the second condition is that a traction of $1e6$ is applied on $x-$direction.

Now, I need to provide boundary conditions for the rest of the boundary $\Omega \setminus (A \cup B)$. As the surface is kind of free, I think a homogeneous Neumann boundary condition should be correct, i.e.

- $\sigma(u_D) \cdot n=0$ on $\partial \Omega \setminus (A \cup B)$

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried conditions resembling: Point x shall not move, being attached to a very rigid structure.  Point y shall have a load placed on it in a direction.

Comment: I don't understand what you are referring to with Point x and Point y, I'm sorry, could you elaborate? @Abel

Comment: You have points (or areas) where your clevis is prevented from moving in some way, and similarly where loads are applied.  These are the boundary conditions.

Comment: Sure, what it's not clear to me is where you would locate those areas (with reference the attached figure). Sorry for not being clear! @Abel

Comment: The holes in the clevis. One set where the pin goes, and one where the rod threads in.  These are also where other parts attach or make contact.  Things that are far apart and not extremely massive tend to apply pretty negligible forces so look for contact surfaces...

Comment: @Abel Thanks again. I edited my question with what I understood from your latest comment. Does it look correct to you? My understanding is that on the two holes there's no displacement, and on the other one we have a prescribed traaction (i.e. a non-homogeneous Neumann boundary condition). As the rest of the boundary is traction free, there one should only impose Neumann homogeneous.

Comment: You should look at stresses on a screw separately (usually just looking it up max loads in a table) , and apply load to the the rod that threads in. You can also model the pin, in the clevis and apply the displacement constraint to the pin.  Things tend to get more representative of reality as you get further (in nodes) away your boundary conditions.  This is because boundary conditions are themselves an approximation made outside your FEA (and so are limited in how much your mesh can affect them)